# Найти самую длинную общую последовательность двух строк

Tags: javascript

Не знаю как найти самую длинную общую последовательность двух строк. 
Например, Строка А "aababba", Строка Б "abbaabcd" и Результат "abba"

Знаю, что задача очень простая, но решение найти не смог. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Может быть, подпоследовательность? Или подстроку? По примеру неясно. В любом случае Гугл миллионы результатов предлагает, так что в `найти не смог` не верится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const finder = (line1, line2) => {
   arr = [];
   line1.split('').reduce((last,item)=>{
     if (line2.indexOf(`${last}${item}`) !== -1) {
         arr.push(`${last}${item}`);
         return `${last}${item}`;
     }
     else return item;
   }, '');
   return arr.sort((a, b)=>b.length-a.length)[0]
}
```